# Does any documentations with mathematical description of Bitcoin exist?

Tags: blockchain, documentation

Does any documentations with mathematical description of Bitcoin exist? Some documentations like YellowPaper in Ethereum?

Comment: The Ethereum Yellowpaper isn't even considered documentation. Its a specification for Ethereum.

Comment: there is an original whitepaper, yes

Comment: Get the "Mastering Bitcoin" book by Antonopoulos. It covers the encryption math and includes the original whitepaper.

Answer (score 1):

- [Etherium Yellow paper, Wood](https://gavwood.com/paper.pdf)
- [Bitcoin Whitepaper, Nakamoto](https://bitcoin.org/bitcoin.pdf)
- [Mastering Bitcoin, Antonopoulos](https://github.com/bitcoinbook/bitcoinbook)
- [The Fallacy of Selfish Mining in Bitcoin: A Mathematical Critique, Wright](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3004026)
- [Research Perspectives and Challenges for Bitcoin
  and Cryptocurrencies, Bonneau et al](https://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.857/2015/files/BMCNKF15-IEEESP-bitcoin.pdf)

etc.